# Why was automatic semi-colon insertion (ASI) added to javascript?

Tags: javascript, standards

Because of a "religious war" at my current work place I have decided to research the history of the ASI feature of javascript.

But I am having trouble finding out why and when ASI was introduced to javascript.

It seems like it has been a feature forever, but is there a specific reason for there to be two ways to terminate a statement in javascript?

Some sources describe ASI as an error-correction feature, which would imply that omitting semi-colons is bad practice.

Is there any performance impacts on relying on ASI?

Personally I prefer semicolons because it makes intentions more explicit, but personal preference isn't a viable argument in any serious discussion.

Comment: It's weird to hear that whether to use semicolons in Javascript is still a debate.

Comment: If you want an answer to such a question, go to a forum where the original author might respond. Or just [*do a search*](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=brendan+eich+why+automatic+semicolon+insertion&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=GwudVbqjIaTu8wfLy5foCA).

Comment: If you fight a religious war then you should have your own arguments - google for arguments is, imho, a point that your arguments don't have a strong point.. fighting wars has never been easy - except you have strong points ;)

Comment: AFAIK one of the requirements was that the language would be easy to use, also by inexperienced programmers. Being fault-tolerant (i.e. automatically inserting missing semicolons) seems to serve this.

Comment: Stefan, my point in using "religious war" in OP was to emphasize that there simply doesn't seem to be no good arguments for one or the other, having/omitting semicolons in JS is as pointless as religious wars, because they simply do not seem to matter to anyone else than those who fight it. The parser doesn't care, most people doesn't care, personally i don't care that much either, I just want consistensy in the codebase, so I am weighing the pros and cons. Maybe it is time i changed habits, it might be healthy, who knows.

Comment: RobG "just do a search" except i did, and had you not prefixed your question with the a name for a specific author (which happens to be the maker of JS) you wouldn't have had success either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great question!

Brenden Eich designed the JavaScript programming language originally, and I think it is fair to say that he would agree that automatic semicolon insertion is a design flaw in the language.

We shouldn't blame him. He designed the language in a period of just 10 days in 1995, having no idea that 20 years later it would become (probably) the most important computer language on the planet.

In the following post he says "I wish I had made newlines more significant in JS back in those ten days in May, 1995."

https://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/

Read on... :)

Comment: I guess that it doesn't get more close to a real answer than this. Thanks, I had trouble finding this on google...

Comment: Making newlines *"more significant"* doesn't at all suggest that he regrets the ASI decision. In fact it's just the opposite; it shows that he stands behind that decision but wanted better accommodation  for it in the language. If there's no ASI, newlines have zero significance.

Comment: @user1106925 huh, in that post he says: "be careful not to use ASI as if it gave JS significant newlines." it's pretty clear if you read it that he thinks abusing ASI is a bad idea.

Comment: @Spongman: That's different from saying he regrets the decision. He just wishes it had different/better rules. Even if the language didn't have ASI, you still have many of the same problems encountered when accidentally omitting a semicolon. With more significance given to whitespace, semicolon issues are reduced, even if only by the presence of a SyntaxError.